# Word for mac F4 equivalent

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word

I am looking for the word for mac equivalent of the F4 (function 4) key used in word for windows to repeat last action command. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the command you mean is "Redo/Repeat Typing" (as found on the QuickAccess menu-bar), because, as far as I know a "Redo last Action" doesn't exist in Word.

On Windows this is linked to both F4 and to Ctrl-Y.
On MacOS it is Cmd-Y, but is not linked to F4.

(Most Windwos Ctrl-[some key] combinations are Cmd-[some key] in the Mac version.)